# Qt OpenGL Problems encountered upgrading from 5.10.0 to 5.12.1

Tags: qt, opengl, qt5

I have a legacy C++ Qt application which has been upgraded through many, many versions of Qt.  I recently upgraded it from Qt 5.10.0 to 5.12.1 and now, suddenly, both of my OpenGL displays are encountering problems and I cannot figure out why.

***Quick Summary of the Problem:***

The first display draws a 3d surface map.  It's very old (contains a legacy control that uses glew) and it uses the now obsolete QGLWidget.  I cannot change this.

```
class GLAdapterWidget : public QGLWidget
{
    // ...A whole lot of legacy code which has not changed...
public:
    // How I update the display

    void doUpdate()
    {
        someLegacyGLDrawingFunction();
        updateGL();  // fails if attribute Qt::WA_Mapped not set
    }
};
```

The problem now is that once it's loaded, it still appears completely black until I actually click the mouse somewhere within its borders. Then suddenly its GL drawing appears perfectly.  This did not happen in Qt 5.10.0.

Debugging I was able to at least track this to the widget attribute **Qt::WA_Mapped** . That attribute is NOT set on my widget and so Qt will not draw it until I click within it. Once I click within its borders Qt sets that attribute, it works fine.  But my attempts at a workaround (e.g. calling show() or trying to set that attribute in software) had no effect.

The second display is more modern and uses QOpenGLWidget.   It shows a live camera image that is updated continuously.

```
class VideoDisplay : public QOpenGLWidget, 
                     protected QOpenGLFunctions_3_3_Core
{

    virtual void initializeGL() override
    {
        initializeOpenGLFunctions();
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-width()/2, width()/2, height()/2, -height()/2, -1, 1); 
        glClearColor(0.25f,0.25f,0.25f,1.0f);

    }
    virtual void paintGL() override
    {
        // Legacy Code that draws a live image using glDrawPixels and which has not changed.
    }
    virtual void resizeGL(int w, int h) override
    {
        glViewport(0,0,w,h);
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glOrtho(-w/2, w/2, h/2, -h/2, -1, 1);
    }
};
```

This one seems to work fine at first.  The image shows up and updates.  But if I go display an instance of the older, GLAdapterWidget and then come back to this display (VideoDisplay), it suddenly appears black and nothing can make it redraw.  Debugging I see paintGL is still being called and it has a valid image.  All the parameters look good.  But nothing shows.

I realize that's not a lot to go on.  This code is so old and large that I feel posting large chunks of it wouldn't do much but muddle matters.

And I realize that the culprit might all be the older QGLWidget-based display in both these cases.  But I 'm not kidding when I say I cannot jettison that code, no matter how much I might like to do so

So I am (desperately) focusing on the fact that this worked in 5.10.0 and does not in 5.12.1  ***What I'm hoping is that someone with a better knowledge of Qt can identify any particular key architectural Qt changes between 5.10.0 and 5.12.1 which might be a culprit here to give me an avenue for investigation or workarounds to try***.

I need a band-aid.  I don't mind doing the work, I just don't know where to start.

Comment: So here's what you do: create a bug-reproducer branch in your repository, switch to that, and start tossing away everything irrelevant to the problem. You should be left with just a few hundred lines strewn across a few sources and headers, that you'll then squeeze into a single `main.cpp` that begins with `#include <QtOpenGL>` (and likely nothing else), ends with `#include "main.moc"`, and fits within SO format :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reported this issue to Qt here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72668 along with a hacky workaround until it is resolved.

> Workaround: Install a QTimer on the parent QMainWindow that's set to a certain interval. After the window is exposed and after the child QOpenGLWidget isValid() returns true, resize the widget to a different size (note: it cannot be the same size, nor does repaint(), update(), or update(0, 0, width, height) work)

```
    QWindow *window = windowHandle();
    if(window && window->isExposed() && glWidget->isValid()) {
        resize(801,601);
        _timer.stop();
    }
```

Comment: I had a feeling someone else might have been seeing this.  Appreciate your taking the time to write this

Comment: Yeah no problem this bug is affecting us here at work as well. Like you, we have a lot of legacy code that depends on QGLWidget too.